# Is this a suitable question for Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, font

There is a particular font that I want to use. I don't know what it's called, but I can scan in an example.

Is Ask Ubuntu the appropriate place to ask something like "Is this font available for Ubuntu, and if so, how do I install it?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few component questions here:

- "What is this font?" — Probably off-topic.
- "What formats is this font available as?" — Again, fairly off-topic and probably answered by the first question.
- "Does Ubuntu support this format of font?" — On topic.
- "How do I install this font?" — On topic.

On balance, the first half is probably more one for a design SE site (honestly not sure where is best) or even just [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) for some self-help.

Then once you know what the font is available as, you could either look for [questions about installing fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191778/how-to-install-fonts-fast-and-easy) or ask a new one about your particular font if it isn't a OTF or TTF font format.

Comment: Graphic design accepts "what font is this" questions.

Comment: What The Font couldn't help but suggested [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com), which identified the font as "Love Ya Like A Sister".

Comment: Which [is available as a stadard TTF](http://www.dafont.com/love-ya-like-a-sister.font). So normal install procedure.